# LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget

Tags: android, listview, casting

```
    @Override  
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

        ListViewItem item = items.get(position);    

        View vi=convertView;
        if(position == 0) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_twolinetext_checkbox, null);
            TextView tvRowTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle);
            TextView tvRowDesc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvRowDesc);
            CheckBox cbCheckBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.cbRowCheckBox);

            tvRowTitle.setText(item.Title);
            tvRowDesc.setText(item.Description);
            return vi;
        } else {

            TwoLineListItem twoLineListItem = (TwoLineListItem) vi;   <----- here is the error

            TextView text1 = twoLineListItem.getText1();
            TextView text2 = twoLineListItem.getText2();

            text1.setText(item.Title);
            text2.setText(item.Description);
            return vi; 
        }


    }

07-10 13:55:37.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10520): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TwoLineListItem
07-10 13:55:37.082: E/AndroidRuntime(10520):  at com.example.util.CustomSettingsListViewAdapter.getView(CustomSettingsListViewAdapter.java:69)
```

Other people that have this issue just clean their project and it works... Maybe my issue is different. Any ideas on why it would give me this issue?

Comment: show code for TwoLineListItem

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the view coming in is of type LinearLayout.  But you are expecting it to be a TwoLineListItem at this point.  Since TwoLineListItem is not a LinearLayout it complains.  Perhaps you just need to figure out why at this position you are getting a linear layout.  Perhaps you meant to skip position 1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a code fragment from an adapter. In the situation where the items in a list managed by the adapter can have different view types, you should override getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position)

Your code then looks a bit like:

```
@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    int itemViewType = getViewType(position);

    View vi=convertView;
    if(itemViewType == 0) {
        // Viewtype 0 is a linear layout?
        if(! (vi instanceof LinearLayout) ) {
           // Cant reuse existing view, inflate a new one..
           vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_twolinetext_checkbox, null);
        }
        TextView tvRowTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle);
        TextView tvRowDesc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvRowDesc);
        CheckBox cbCheckBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.cbRowCheckBox);

        tvRowTitle.setText(item.Title);
        tvRowDesc.setText(item.Description);

    } else if(itemViewType == 1) {
        // TwoLineListItem
        if(!vi instanceof TwoLineListItem) {
          // Can't reuse layout, inflate a new one.. 
          vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twolinelistitem, null);
        }

        TwoLineListItem twoLineListItem = (TwoLineListItem) vi;  
        TextView text1 = twoLineListItem.getText1();
        TextView text2 = twoLineListItem.getText2();

        text1.setText(item.Title);
        text2.setText(item.Description);

    }

    return vi;
}
```

The important thing to note is that the convertView is actually retrieved from the ListAdapter's "recycle" bin to try and reduce the number of allocations/GCs as you are scrolling through the list. You should examine the type of view in convertView before trying to use it and create a new layout if it isn't the one you need.

getItemViewType(position) should return your view type number for the position in the list. In your case it would probably be simpler to do directly in your getView, but by doing it "properly" you can then decide later if you want to have a mix of views.. e.g:

now:

```
 @Override
 int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if(position == 0) {
     return 0;
   } else {
     return 1;
   }
 }
```

future:

```
 @Override
 int getItemViewType(int position) {

    SpecialData item = (SpecialData) getItem(position);

    if(item.isTwoLineItem()) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
 }
```